# How to initialize a peewee SQLite database at runtime?

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I'm ussing peewee for my sqlite database. I wrote a module which contains the database models. In the first code snippet of the [doc](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#creating-model-tables) it is explained how the database is initialized:

**db_model.py**

```py
import datetime
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('my_app.db')

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class User(BaseModel):
    username = CharField(unique=True)

class Tweet(BaseModel):
    user = ForeignKeyField(User, backref='tweets')
    message = TextField()
    created_date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    is_published = BooleanField(default=True)
```

In my understanding, the database is initialized the moment the module is import? I am looking for a way to initialize the database during runtime? How can I achieve this?

Comment: No, the database is not initialised during import, this is the ORM (Object-Relational Mapping) which is initialised.

Comment: Can you detail you problem?

Comment: I would like to set the path to the database outside of the module. In this example it looks like the database path is hardcoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the docs. "Run-time database configuration" seems relevant:

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#run-time-database-configuration

For instance, initialize the `db` object with `None`:

```py
db = SqliteDatabase(None)
```

... and later in your application:

```
db.init(<actual parameters>)
```